# mypy fails to detect type inconsistency in inherited method

Tags: python, typing, mypy

I'm trying to type-annotate two coupled, generic classes that must agree on a type (which they use to exchange data).

Here's a made-up example, involving commands that can be executed via runners. `Command` is generic over a `Runner` subclass and vice versa -- this allows, a command to adapt to the runner in which it is executing. For example, a `LinuxCommand` might require a `LinuxRunner` so that it can adapt to the latter's `kernel_version` attribute. In addition, both classes are generic over the type of "message" they expect (`T`).

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Any, Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')
C = TypeVar('C', bound='Command[Any, Any]')
R = TypeVar('R', bound='Runner[Any, Any]')

class Command(ABC, Generic[R, T]):
    @abstractmethod
    def execute(self, runner: R) -> T:
        pass

class Runner(Generic[C, T]):
    def run(self, command: C) -> T:
        return command.execute(self)
```

My goal is to ensure (via mypy) that only compatible commands and runners can be combined. However, mypy 0.790 does *not* complain about the following:

```py
class BrokenStrCommand(Command['BrokenIntRunner', str]):
    def execute(self, runner: BrokenIntRunner) -> str:
        return 'foo'

class BrokenIntRunner(Runner[BrokenStrCommand, int]):
    pass

str_command = BrokenStrCommand()
int_runner = BrokenIntRunner()
result: int = int_runner.run(str_command)
print(result)  # prints 'foo'
```

I would have expected that the definition of `BrokenIntRunner` triggers a type error, since its `run` method takes an instance of `BrokenStrCommand`, gets a `str` from its `execute` method and returns it -- despite its return type being `int`.

`reveal_type` says that the type of `int_runner.run` is

```
def (command: mypy_sandbox.BrokenStrCommand*) -> builtins.int*
```

and that the type of `BrokenStrCommand.execute` is

```
def (self: mypy_sandbox.BrokenStrCommand, runner: mypy_sandbox.BrokenIntRunner) -> builtins.str
```

Hence, mypy should have all the necessary information to detect that the types don't match.